# Storing Large Form Data JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, forms, validation, cookies

I am learning JavaScript to make a large form that stays completely local( no web server involved what-so-ever ).  I am very familiar with PHP, but JavaScript is new to me.  I have a form that has 100+ checkboxes and text fields.  Some of the fields show as "[X] Other: [/*text field*/]" so when you select the "other" selection, you have to enter an input.  I am making a validation to make sure you, A: enter text if you selected "other." B: make sure you selected the check box if you have entered text.  When the validation function finds something wrong, it shows an alert box.  Then, the page reloads( Not sure why ) and all of the data put into the form is wiped.  So, I need to find a way to store this form data to load it upon page reload.  I started with cookies, but then it came upon me that there is limits to the number of cookies and their sizes.  What else can I do??? Please help!

Comment: localStorage would be ideal for you

Comment: Sounds like you should fix the reload issue after the `alert`. I think users would find this pretty annoying. What type of `input` are you using to start the validation/submit the form?

Comment: thank you @marizikmund I will use this.

Comment: @jasonscript I am using a submit button

Comment: `submit` buttons will always submit the page to server. `submit` buttons are related to `form` and `form action`. If you're not submitting to a server (php, node, .NET, etc.), then you don't need to use a `submit`

Comment: @jasonscript ok... how can I change this? I have a function "submitted()" that gets called when the form is submitted but that is in the form line: <button type="submit" id="subbutton">Submit!</button>

Comment: @jasonscript whoops bad copy/paste... this is the form line: <form name="main" method="post">.  Then, the button line is <button type="submit" id="subbutton">Submit!</button>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `submit` button is reloading the page.

For example, if your form is set up like this:

```
<form name="main" method="post">
   <!-- Lots of input fields -->
   <button type="submit" id="subbutton">Submit!</button>
</form>
```

This is doing a `POST` to an undefined server because your `form` has no `action`

If you're sure that you don't need any server interaction at all, it's not necessary to use a `form` element

This means you can remove the `form` and `submit` elements from your page and use a `button` element instead

```
<!-- Lots of input fields -->
<button id="clientaction" type="button">Click me</button>
```

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/form):

> The HTML  element represents a document section that contains
>   interactive controls to submit information to a web server.